# How to pass post data to asp.net web api method in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post

ASP.NET MVC Web API application defines post method to shortlist userDetails which uses complex-view model data.

I have written an Ajax call which works successfully.

Now same call I need to write in objective c.

```
$.ajax(
                                     {
                                     type: "POST",
                                     url: API_URL + "ShortList",
                                     data:
                                     {
                                     User:
                                     {
                                     UserGuid: user_guid,
                                     UserID: user_id
                                     }
                                     },
                                     dataType: "json",
                                     success: function(response)
                                     {});
```

Above call is slightly different as it has complex model data

i.e it takes data as case 1)

```
data:{
      User:{
            UserGuid: user_guid,
            UserID: user_id
           }
     },
```

Case 2)And not as

```
 data:{
       email: username,
       password: password
       },
```

If it was a case2) then I could have used

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",self.UserName.text,self.userPassword.text];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

How to write post method call for case 1 (i.e in case of complex data call)?

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C you can use Nsurlconnection like if you want to call a signup api you have to pass as a dictionry like

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:@"john" forKey:@"firstname"];
[params setObject:@"peter" forKey:@"lastname"];
[params setObject:@"12345678" forKey:@"password"];
[params setObject:@"12-12-2001" forKey:@"DOB"];
[self sendRequestWithPostType:@"post" andURL:@"signup" andParams:params forTag:100];
```

and method for post api call is here we need to convert dictionary into json string

```
- (void) sendRequestWithPostType:(NSString *)postType andURL:(NSString *)strURL andParams:(NSDictionary *)parameters forTag:(int)Tag{


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/?device_id=%@",BASE_URL,strURL,jsonString];
NSLog(@"%@",temp);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
NSLog(@"Did Receive Response %@", response);
responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error{
NSLog(@"Did Fail");}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data{
NSLog(@"Did Receive Data %@", data);
[responseData appendData:data];}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSLog(@"Did Finish");
jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
            JSONObjectWithData:responseData
            options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
            error:nil];

NSLog(@"jsonObject is %@",jsonObject);}
```

It will work for you ,....

Answer (score 0):

in Case 1 your postData string will be :

```
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserGuid=%@&user_id=%@",[[data objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"UserGuid"],[[data objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"UserID"]];
```